# Is $K\cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the  following statement true/false?

> Let $(\mathbb{F},+,\cdot)$ be the finite field with $9$ elements. Let $K=(\mathbb{F},+)$   denote the underlying additive  group;  then
>   $$K\cong (\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$$

My attempt:  I thinks this statement  is false  because  $\gcd(3,3)= 3 \neq 1$

Is  my logic correct?

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Comment: Why would $\gcd(3, 3)\neq 1$ prove the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement is true; $\mathbb{F}$ is a vector space over the three-element field and has dimension $2$. The same holds for $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$.

It is false that $\mathbb{F}\cong(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})$ as *rings*.

Comment: @@@egreq  that mean $\mathbb{Z} /3\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z} /3\mathbb{Z}= \mathbb{Z_9}  $  or  $\mathbb{F_9} $ ?  which one  u r saying

Comment: @jasmine It is **not** true that $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\simeq\mathbb{Z}_9$.

Comment: @freakish that mean  $\mathbb{F_9}$ is True ??

Comment: @jasmine The statement in the question (isomorphism as abelian group) is *true*. The statement that $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ is *false*.

Comment: @egreg thanks  u  .

Answer (score 1):

It's an abelian group with nine elements, where each element has order $3$. There is only one such group (which I suppose is what you *actually* need to prove).